# DataWeave populate field based on self lookup in payload

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a use case where we're looking to generate a flat-file based off HRIS data.

We retrieve one payload of employee data to include `manager`

The use case is to populate an `isManager` field if any record has that user as a manager.

I was able to retrieve an employee's manager, but walking down the tree is throwing me for a loop.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var levelsPayload = payload[0].payload
var employeesPayload = payload[1].payload
var allManagerIds = employeesPayload.managerId
---
employeesPayload map (employee) -> {
    id: employee.id,
    endDate: employee.endDate,
    isManager: allManagerIds contains employee.id,
    manager: ((employeesPayload filter ( (value, index) -> value.id == employee.manager )) map ( (value,index) -> (value.preferredFirstName ++ ' ' ++ value.preferredLastName) )) joinBy (""),
    managerEmail: ((employeesPayload filter ( (value, index) -> value.id == employee.manager )) map ( (value,index) -> value.workEmail )) joinBy (""),
    firstName: employee.preferredFirstName default employee.firstName,
    lastName: if (employee.preferredLastName == '' or employee.preferredLastName == null) employee.lastName else employee.preferredLastName,
    userName: employee.workEmail,
    email: employee.workEmail,
    title: employee.title replace /(,)/ with " ",
    displayName: employee.preferredFirstName ++ ' ' ++ employee.preferredLastName,
    secondEmail: employee.personalEmail,
    primaryPhone: employee.phone,
    streetAddress: '',
    city: employee.address.city,
    state: employee.address.state,
    zipCode: employee.address.zip,
    countryCode: employee.address.country,
    postalAddress: employee.address.zip,
    employeeNumber: employee.employeeNumber,
    department: employee.department,
    managerId: employee.manager,
    startDate: employee.startDate,
    jobStatus: if (employee.endDate == null) "active" else "termed",
    teams: (employee.teams joinBy '') as String,
    level: ((levelsPayload as Array filter ( (value, index) -> value.id == employee.level )) map ( (value,index) -> value.name as String) ) joinBy (""),
    employmentType:  employee.employmentType,
    legalFirstName: employee.firstName,
    legalLastName: employee.lastName,
}
```

I'd assume I need to do a filter map, but am unsure how to return `true` if any element in the payload equals the manager's employee id

Comment: not sure what exactly you are looking for. is it possible to post what is the input and expected output

Comment: @HarshaShivamurthy I updated to show full dwl

Comment: Could you pls share the input and expected output payloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all manager IDs in a `var`

```
var allManagerIds = employeesPayload.manager
```

Then you can use `contains` method to check if a the employee manager id is in this list.

```
isManager: allManagerIds contains employee.manager
```

Comment: thanks, this was simpler than I was thinking